# Importing a Gradle project in IntelliJ using different java jdk version

Tags: java, gradle

I tried to import a gradle project in IntelliJ and I'm getting the following error :

`Error:Could not determine java version from '9.0.4'.`

As said is the gradle project in `java 1.8 ( exactly  1.8.0_152)` and the version on my `Linux is 9.0.4`.

I think I should downgrade the version from `9.0.4` to this `1.8.0_152` but I don't know how to do it.
Can I fix the problem without downgrading the `Java` version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well known bug! Here you can find the issue documentation with a possible solution on github: [#16536](http://Gradle%20distribution%20needs%20to%20be%20updated%20in%20order%20to%20work%20with%20JDK%20v9%20#16536)

> Edit the file /android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and update the last line with:
>   `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-rc-2-all.zip`

Alternate I found this intellij specific [solution](https://peterdaugaardrasmussen.com/2018/01/27/intellij-idea-gradle-error-could-not-determine-java-version-from-9-0-1/), solved by pointing intellij at a location of a custom gradle install:

```
"File > Settings... > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle > Use local gradle distribution"
```